# Completely remove MariaDB 10.01 in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: sql, mariadb

I am having a problem while trying to **completely purge** Maria DB and install it again.

This is what I do to remove it :

```
 2073  sudo apt-get remove --purge maria*
 2074  rm -f /var/log/mariadb
 2075  rm -f /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log
 2076  rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
 2077  rm -rf /usr/lib64/mysql
 2078  rm -rf /usr/share/mysql
```

And then I attempt to reinstall as :

```
sudo apt install mariadb-server
mysql_secure_installation
```

But the problem is once I do it I am being prompted for the root password, which should not be set as I have **supposedly** purged everything.

#### Output from mysql_secure_installation :

```
[~]@Ubuntu1804  #> mysql_secure_installation 

NOTE: RUNNING ALL PARTS OF THIS SCRIPT IS RECOMMENDED FOR ALL MariaDB
      SERVERS IN PRODUCTION USE!  PLEASE READ EACH STEP CAREFULLY!

In order to log into MariaDB to secure it, we'll need the current
password for the root user.  If you've just installed MariaDB, and
you haven't set the root password yet, the password will be blank,
so you should just press enter here.

Enter current password for root (enter for none): 
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
Enter current password for root (enter for none): 
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
Enter current password for root (enter for none): 
Aborting!
```

If I leave it blank it fails, but If I try with the right password it fails as well.

How can I remove **everything** related to MariaDB from the server?

Comment: You probably should have done `sudo apt remove mariadb-server`.  i Think you somewhere have a `my.cnf`, problably in `/etc` ?

Comment: @Luuk Thanks for your reply Luuk. I ended up removing an entire folder called mysql in /etc and now it worked.

Answer (score 38):

## Just run this command

```
sudo apt-get purge mariadb-*
```

Answer (score 0):

So in my case, I ended up going to **/etc** and removing the folder called *mysql*. It looks obvious but I thought that it would be done automatically when *removing*? the app via the package manager.

Comment: Apt keeps some configuration files if you remove a package. To completely remove everything, use the `purge` option (and probably accept the answer which tells you this).